# Put a title property on image gallery

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create an image gallery as shown below. It's working fine but I need to put a title below the image (each and every image has a title). When I have tried like below - that title is not showing correctly. Can you show me how to do that?

**Html**

```
<ul id="thumbnailsList">
    <li *ngFor="let image of datasource">

        <img src="{{image.url}}" class="tn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selectedImageModal" (click)=setSelectedImage(image)>
        <div class="myClass"><strong>{{image.title}}</strong></div>


    </li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.myClass {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Result :**

[image]

**Update :**

When I removed the `.myClass` it shows like below.But I need to show images horizontally and text bottom of the image.

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to look like the image on the left? T1?

Comment: I need to put the title below each and every image @MichaelCoker

Comment: then why not just use the HTML you have, and remove `position: absolute;` from `.myClass`? A div will be displayed below the image by default without additional CSS.

Comment: no it's not working where I need it.please see the **Update** section @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using Bootstrap responsive design.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let image of dataCollection" class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img class="img-responsive tn" src="{{image.blobFileUrl}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selectedImageModal" (click)=setSelectedImage(image) />
        <div class="desc">{{image.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 div.desc {
     padding: 15px;
     text-align: center;
 }

.tn {
    margin: 2px 0px;
    box-shadow: #999 1px 1px 3px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 200px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work using position:absolute, you need to give a parent container a position property doing:

```
#thumbnailsList li
   position: relative
```

Comment: not working.it still shows as like my 1st image.no difference.